# multibranch pipeline - how to merge

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to merge develop to master on Jenkins declarative pipeline, but Jenkins doesn't clone all the project.

When I use `git checkout master` - the error is:

```
pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What should I do in order to merge automatically to master?

Comment: Please show us the whole Jenkinsfile.